# create a gadget in dashboard designer of DAS WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I created a tenant in WSO2 DAS and I am authenticated with that tenant. I created a stream event, when I go to the dashboard designer and try to create a gadget I get the following error.

```
[2016-02-11 12:08:15,207] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.jsservice.AnalyticsJSServiceConnector} -  Failed to get the table schema for table: TT : [-1234:TT] does not exist org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.commons.exception.AnalyticsTableNotAvailableException: [-1234:TT] does not exist
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me.

Go to the file:

```
<DAS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/controllers/apis/analytics.jag
```

and change line 80 to: 
`loggedInUser = token[USERNAME]+"@"+token["domain"];`

Answer (score 0):

If you created the stream by logging using tenant credentials, you need to log into Analytic Dashboards using same tenant credentials. Streams created for one tenant is not available for other tenants. According to your screenshot you have been logged using admin credentials.

Comment: no, says admin becouse the tenant created  was admin@test.com. But I am loged in Dashboard designer as admin@test.com. The table/event stream that I can access correspond to this tenant. The problem is when I select table/event,  the system not show the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I am using a tenant credentials to access the dashboard designer and when I try to create a gadget I get the same problem, if I do it with the super tenant I can create the gadget without problem.